# Escape & by scrapy shell

Tags: shell, scrapy

When I run the command

```
scrapy shell http://www.example.com/moreKJinfo.asp?cptype=1&inqs=2017063
```

Then, when I fetch the url with `response.url`, I have `http://www.example.com/moreKJinfo.asp?cptype=1` which is missing `&inqs=2017063?`

How can I escape `&` in scrapy shell?

Comment: You have to ask your question in English.

Comment: @Mr.wu, there's a note on this [in the tutorial](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#extracting-data).

Answer (score 1):

Just run `scrapy shell "http://www.example.com/moreKJinfo.asp?cptype=1&inqs=2017063"` (**don't forget the quotes**)

Then you'll have:

```
In [1]: response.url
Out[1]: 'http://www.example.com/moreKJinfo.asp?cptype=1&inqs=2017063'
```